# Laravel how many relationship can be chained

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.1

I have a database composed by users, users_child, child.

I create a ONE to MANY relationship between Users and users_child, then i create a relationship between users_child and child. Now the below code work:

```
    $test = users::find(1)->users_child
    $test1= users_child::find(1)->child
```

Now i want to know if is possible to create a single row that link the three table like this:

```
    $test = users::find(1)->users_child->child
```

I create the relationship in the model but in the db i don't create Foreign Key, it's a problem? on the model i specify the field for link table.

Comment: The subtable users_child seems like a many to many relationship? If so: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: No users_child to child is onetoone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

You can chain relationships like this:

```
$user = Users::with("users_child.child")->where("id",1)->first();
```

Each point will mean a relation stored in the first.

Out of users users_child will be taken and out of users_child child will be taken. (Relations)

```
foreach($user->users_child as $user_child) {
    $user_child->child;
}
```

will get you the data you need.

Comment: Did it work? or are you still looking for the right solution?

Comment: I hope to try this tonight... i'm very busy

Comment: OK, if i make a DD($user) i can see all the data correctly, but i can't use $user->users_child->child  for navigating the property. It doesn't work

Comment: Well one to many means an array of outputs try to run $user->users_child trough a foreach then get child out of it like I have changed in my awnser.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Solved